# iOS: Resolve DNS SRV records

Tags: ios, swift, dns

Im my iOS application, I want to resolve the DNS service records (SRV) of a domain.

I found some libraries that allows to do this, but the response is empty. One of the library that I tried is [DNS](https://github.com/Bouke/DNS). The code looks sometihng like this:

```
import UIKit
import DNS

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let url = "_registration._tcp.gateway.zeeotp.com"
    print("Starting discovery")
    
    do {
    let request = Message(
        type: .query,
        authoritativeAnswer: false, 
        questions: [Question(name: url, type: .service)]
    )
    let requestData = try request.serialize()
    
    // Decoding a message
    let responseData = requestData
    let response = try Message.init(deserialize: responseData)
    print(response)
    } catch {
        print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
    }
  }

}
```

And the output I get is:

> DNS Request(id: 0, authoritativeAnswer: false, truncation: false, recursionDesired: false, recursionAvailable: false, questions: [DNS.Question(name: "_registration._tcp.gateway.zeeotp.com.", type: SRV, unique: false, internetClass: A)], answers: [], authorities: [], additional: [])

During my research I came accross [SRVResolver](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SRVResolver/Listings/Read_Me_About_SRVResolver_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009625-Read_Me_About_SRVResolver_txt-DontLinkElementID_3) but it is in Objective-C and I have no clue how to make it work with Swift.

Is there something that I am missing in the ablove code to make it work correctly?

Comment: There may be something wrong in your use, as `internetClass: A` seems wrong. It should be `IN` if `class` here means `class` as in DNS terminology.

Comment: Even if I pass the internetClass as `IN` in the `Question` constructor, it is deserialized as an `A` class.

Comment: The problem is that this library doesn't actually perform the DNS query, it simply handles the converting of dns query objects into `Data` that you can send to a DNS server and the conversion of received `Data` back into an object. Your code is just decoding the data that it encoded (`responseData = requestData`), so you end up with no answer because you didn't actually ask the question.

Comment: @Paulw11Yes makes sense. Based on this, I tried to find a way to query the public DNS service with this data, but all I could find was resoving IP from the host using the [CFNetwork](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork) class. If you have any idea regarding how query the DNS and could point me towards it, it would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying various things, I finally was able to make this work. As mentioned in comments by @Paulw11, the library [DNS](https://github.com/Bouke/DNS) did not send the actual DNS request and hence I was not getting the desired result.

**Option 1:**

I finally decided to integrate the Objective-C [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SRVResolver/Listings/Read_Me_About_SRVResolver_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009625-Read_Me_About_SRVResolver_txt-DontLinkElementID_3) provided by Apple into my Swift application. To do so,

1. I added the [SRVResolver.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SRVResolver/Listings/SRVResolver_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009625-SRVResolver_h-DontLinkElementID_4) and [SRVResolver.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SRVResolver/Listings/SRVResolver_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009625-SRVResolver_m-DontLinkElementID_5) into my project
2. Created a bridging header file and added:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#include "SRVResolver.h"
```

3. Added `libresolv.tbd` in  *Link Binary With Libraries* section under target's *Build Phases*

Now in my `ViewController.swift` I was able to use it as follows to get the `priority`, `weight` and `hostname` values:

```
let url = "_registration._tcp.gateway.zeeotp.com"
print("Starting discovery")
    
let resolver = SRVResolver.init(srvName: url)
assert(resolver != nil)
resolver?.delegate = self
resolver?.start()
while !(resolver!.isFinished) {
    RunLoop.current.run(mode: .default, before: Date.distantFuture)
}
    
if(resolver?.error == nil) {
    for result in resolver?.results ?? [] {
        let dataArray = result as! NSDictionary;
            
        for (key, value) in dataArray { // loop through data items
            print("\(key) -> \(value)")
        }
    }
} else {
    print("Error: \(String(describing: resolver?.error))")
}
```

**Option: 2**

I also found an external library [NioDNS](https://github.com/OpenKitten/NioDNS) that allows us to do some DNS operations. Using this library also I was able to retrieve the SRV records. In my `ViewController.swift` I added the following code:

```
import NIO
import DNSClient

let loop: MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup!

do {
    loop = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: 1)

    let client = try DNSClient.connect(on: loop).wait()
    let records = try client.getSRVRecords(from: url).wait()
    for record in records {
        print(record.resource.weight)
        print(record.resource.priority)
        print(record.resource.domainName.string)
    }
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `error - UnableToParseConfig()` after DNSClient.connect? Unsure as to what the cause is

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this later, you can now do this in pure swift without the legacy objective C SRVResolver, nor any third party libraries. Using the DNSServiceQueryRecord API: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dnssd/1804747-dnsservicequeryrecord

See example code how to use for SRV records here: https://github.com/jamf/NoMAD-2/blob/main/NoMAD/SRVLookups/SRVResolver.swift

There is way more detail in the link, but the main parts to get familiar with are
First set up up a DNSServiceQueryRecordReply as a callback when you hear results back

```
let queryCallback: DNSServiceQueryRecordReply = { (sdRef, flags, interfaceIndex, errorCode, fullname, rrtype, rrclass, rdlen, rdata, ttl, context) -> Void in
    
    guard let context = context else { return }
    
    let request: SRVResolver = SRVResolver.bridge(context)

    if let data = rdata?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self),
       let record = SRVRecord(data: Data.init(bytes: data, count: Int(rdlen))) {
        request.results.append(record)
    }
    
    if ((flags & kDNSServiceFlagsMoreComing) == 0) {
        request.success()
    }
}
```

Then calling DNSServiceQueryRecord to send the request, specifying kDNSServiceType_SRV to only receive SRV results.

```
let result = DNSServiceQueryRecord(&self.serviceRef, kDNSServiceFlagsReturnIntermediates, UInt32(0), namec,  UInt16(kDNSServiceType_SRV),  UInt16(kDNSServiceClass_IN), queryCallback, SRVResolver.bridge(self))
```

and finally, calling DNSServiceProcessResult to start reading the results of the DNS query

```
let res = DNSServiceProcessResult(sdRef)
```

You can then use the rdata in the RecordReply callback from earlier to parse the data

```
public struct SRVRecord: Codable, Equatable {
    
    let priority: Int
    let weight: Int
    let port: Int
    let target: String
    
    init?(data: Data) {
        
        var workingTarget = ""
        
        guard data.count > 8 else { return nil }
        priority = Int(data[0]) * 256 + Int(data[1])
        weight = Int(data[2]) * 256 + Int(data[3])
        port = Int(data[4]) * 256 + Int(data[5])
        
        // data[6] will always be a unicode control character
        // starting off the actual hostname, so we skip it
        
        for byte in data[7...(data.count - 1)] {
            if let char = String(data: Data([byte]), encoding: .utf8) {
                
                // strip out the unicode control characters
                // there's probably a better, more complete way
                
                if char == "\u{03}" || char == "\u{04}" || char == "\u{05}"  || char == "\0" {
                    workingTarget += "."
                } else {
                    workingTarget += char
                }
            }
        }
        target = workingTarget
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a third party libray seems overkill for this.  You can achieve the results you want with URLSession.  This example uses [dns query tools](https://dns.query.tools/manage) but there are others available.

```
let apiKey = "your api key"

extension Dictionary : URLQueryParameterStringConvertible {
   var queryParameters: String {
      var parts: [String] = []
      for (key, value) in self {
         let part = String(format: "%@=%@",
                           String(describing: key).addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!,
                           String(describing: value).addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)
         parts.append(part as String)
      }
      return parts.joined(separator: "&")
   }
}


extension URL {
   func appendingQueryParameters(_ parametersDictionary : Dictionary<String, String>) -> URL {
      let URLString : String = String(format: "%@?%@", self.absoluteString, parametersDictionary.queryParameters)
      return URL(string: URLString)!
   }
}


protocol URLQueryParameterStringConvertible {
   var queryParameters: String {get}
}


enum RecordTpe: String {
   case A
   case SRV
   case MX
   case AAA
}


let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
guard var URL = URL(string: "https://dns.query.tools/v1/dns/query") else {fatalError()}

let URLParams = [
   "host": "_registration._tcp.gateway.zeeotp.com",
   "type": RecordTpe.SRV.rawValue,
]

URL = URL.appendingQueryParameters(URLParams)
var request = URLRequest(url: URL)
request.httpMethod = "GET"

request.addValue("Bearer \(apiKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
   if (error == nil) {
      let json = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
      print(json!)
   }
   else {
      print("URL Session Task Failed: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
   }
})
task.resume()
session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
```

I think the extensions were originally from the excellent Paw app, so check it out: [Paw Cloud](https://paw.cloud)

Comment: "Using a third party libray seems overkill for this." But then you use nothing less than a full external website through DOH to do the job. An application shouldn't have those kind of dependencies, itself + OS has everything it needs locally to do DNS queries, no need to rely on a third party, not even thinking about the security and performance consequences...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I agree,   It was a bad example, but just something I had to hand as an example.  I should have just stopped at the comment that adding a third party deoendency was overkill.   I'll remove the answer as it could be misleading.

Comment: There is no harm leaving out your answer. It does answer the question, albeit not exactly in the way the OP wanted, but it provides another view. There should be other answers and people will just vote.