# Get DNS records

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get all DNS recors, like a `dig domain.com any` in unix. I need an answer like the command output:

```
domain.com.     86400   IN  NS  ...
domain.com.     86400   IN  NS  ...
domain.com.     3600    IN  A   ...
domain.com.     300 IN  MX  10 ...
domain.com.     300 IN  MX  10 ...
domain.com.     300 IN  TXT ...
domain.com.     300 IN  TXT ...
domain.com.     86400   IN  SOA ...
```

I tried without success all references that I could found:

- https://gist.github.com/fikeminkel/a9c4bc4d0348527e8df3690e242038d3 : Tried the code in the gist and last comment, returns nothing.
- https://github.com/orlandos-nl/NioDNS : I had to modify the code:

  ```
    do {

        let client = try DNSClient.connect(on: loop).wait()
        let records = try client.sendQuery(forHost: "mercadona.es", type: .any).wait()

        for msg in records.answers {
            switch msg {
            case .aaaa(let resourceRecord):
                print("⚠️.aaaa")
                print(resourceRecord.resource.stringAddress)
            case .a(let resourceRecord):
                print("⚠️.a")
                print(resourceRecord.resource.stringAddress)
            case .txt(let resourceRecord):
                print("⚠️.txt")
                print(resourceRecord.resource.values)
            case .srv(let resourceRecord):
                print("⚠️.srv")
                print(resourceRecord.resource.domainName.string)
            case .mx(let resourceRecord):
                print("⚠️.mx")
                print(resourceRecord.resource.labels.string)
            case .other(let resourceRecord):
                print("⚠️.other")
                print(resourceRecord.resource.description)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
  ```

All answers went for other option. And none of them give me an appropriate address.

- [iOS: Resolve DNS SRV records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66103216/ios-resolve-dns-srv-records) : I'm trying to translate this, because I'm not allowed to enter Objective C in the project.

I expect to get type and value for all dns records.

```
NS ns.domain.com.
MX mx.domain.com.
TXT "whatever_value"
```

How can I do it? Any references are welcome.

Comment: In what way does it “not work”? Compiler error, crash, wrong result? Please be more specific: show the exact code that you tried, together with the actual and the expected results.

Comment: you could try this lib in swift: https://github.com/Dashlane/SwiftDomainParser    of the  "Public Suffix List"